# Singleton Object created every time When I invoke from @EJB

Tags: singleton, ejb

```
@Singleton
public class EntityManagerFactoryUtil implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5769561190804055727L;

/**
 * This attribute mClassname is for logging the Class Name
 */
private final static String mClassName = "EntityManagerFactoryUtil";

/**
 * This attribute mLog used for write to log.
 */
private static Logger mLog = Logger.getLogger(EntityManagerFactoryUtil.class.getName());

/**
 * This method is used to create an instance of Entity Manager Factory.
 * @throws Exception
 * @return entityManagerFactory
 * @author ashokkumar_ks@solartis.net
 * @since  06-Sep-2012
 */
public  EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() throws Exception {
    final String methodName = "getEntityManagerFactory";
    mLog.debug("Entered Class Name ::" + mClassName + " Method Name ::" + methodName);
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory=null;
    try {
        entityManagerFactory =Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("StudentManagementSystem");
    } catch (Exception creationError) {
        mLog.error("Entered ::" + mClassName + "Error ::" +creationError.getMessage());
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(creationError);
    }
    mLog.debug("Exited Class Name ::" + mClassName + "Method Name ::" + methodName + " Object Reference :: " +entityManagerFactory);
    return entityManagerFactory;
}
```

}

---

This is my Business Logi

```
@EJB 
private EntityManagerFactoryUtil mEntityManagerFactory;

public StudentDetail save(StudentDetail studentInformation) {
    final String methodName = "Save";
    mLog.debug("Entered  ClassName::" + mClassName + " MethodName :: " + methodName);
    EntityManager entityManager = null;
    EntityTransaction entityTransaction = null;
    try { 
        entityManager = mEntityManagerFactory.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
        if (entityManager != null && entityManager.isOpen()) {
            entityTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
            if(entityTransaction!=null) {
                entityTransaction.begin();
                if(entityTransaction.isActive()) {

                    // save student information into relation model
                    entityManager.persist(studentInformation);  
                    entityTransaction.commit();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception saveException) {
        try {
            if (entityManager != null && entityManager.isOpen()) {
                if(entityTransaction!=null  && entityTransaction.isActive()) {
                    entityTransaction.rollback();
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception transactionException) {
            mLog.warn("Exception in ClassName :: " + mClassName+ " MethodName::" + methodName + " warn :: "
                    + transactionException.getMessage() + "Student ID :: "+studentInformation.getId());
        }
            mLog.error("Exception in ClassName :: " + mClassName+ " MethodName::" + methodName + " Error :: "
                + saveException.getMessage() + "Student ID :: "+ studentInformation.getId());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (entityManager != null && entityManager.isOpen()) {
                entityManager.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception nullException) {
            mLog.warn("Exception in ClassName :: " + mClassName+ " MethodName::" + methodName + " warn :: "
                    + nullException.getMessage() + " Student ID :: "+ studentInformation.getId());
        }
        mLog.debug("Exited  ClassName::" + mClassName + " MethodName :: "+ methodName + "Student ID :: "+ studentInformation.getId());
    }
    return studentInformation;
}
```

When ever I calling Save method... every time new object created and access business logic.. ?? But Singleton Mean ... One time Instance creation????

10:31:49,413 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) 22754 [http--0.0.0.0-8080-2] DEBUG com.dms.util.EntityManagerFactoryUtil  - Exited Class Name ::EntityManagerFactoryUtilMethod Name ::getEntityManagerFactory Object Reference :: org.hibernate.ejb.**EntityManagerFactoryImpl@130df8**

10:31:56,232 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-3) 29573 [http--0.0.0.0-8080-3] DEBUG com.dms.util.EntityManagerFactoryUtil  - Exited Class Name ::EntityManagerFactoryUtilMethod Name ::getEntityManagerFactory Object Reference :: org.hibernate.ejb.**EntityManagerFactoryImpl@5170a8**

Every time different object created.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got solution.. Please let me know, anything wrong

```
@Startup

@Singleton

public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() throws Exception {
    final String methodName = "getEntityManagerFactory";
    mLog.debug("Entered Class Name ::" + mClassName + " Method Name ::" + methodName);
    try {
        if (!mEntityManagerFactory.isOpen()) {
            createEntityManagerFactory();
        }
    } catch (Exception creationException) {
        mLog.error("Entered ::" + mClassName + " Method Name :: " + methodName + " Error ::" + creationException.getMessage());
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(creationException);
    }
    mLog.debug("Exited Class Name ::" + mClassName + " Method Name :: " + methodName);
    return mEntityManagerFactory;
}

 /**
  * This method is used to create Entity Manager Factory to look the persistence unit name.
  * @author ashokkumar_ks@solartis.net
  * @since  08-Sep-2012
  */
@PostConstruct
public void createEntityManagerFactory() {
    final String methodName = "createEntityManagerFactory";
    mLog.debug("Entered Class Name ::" + mClassName + " Method Name ::"+ methodName);
    try {
        mEntityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("StudentManagementSystem");
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        mLog.error("Entered ::" + mClassName +" Method Name :: "+ methodName + " Error ::" +exception.getMessage());
    }
    mLog.debug("Exited Class Name ::" + mClassName + " Method Name ::" + methodName + " Object Reference :: " +mEntityManagerFactory);
}

/**
 * This method is used to destroy the instance of entityManagerFactory.
 * @author ashokkumar_ks@solartis.net
 * @since 08-Sep-2012
 */
@PreDestroy
public void destroyEntityManagerFactory() {
    final String methodName = "destroyEntityManagerFactory";
    mLog.debug("Entered Class Name ::" + mClassName + " Method Name :: "+ methodName);
    try {
        if (mEntityManagerFactory != null && mEntityManagerFactory.isOpen()) {
            mEntityManagerFactory.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        mLog.error("Entered ::" + mClassName +" Method Name :: "+ methodName + " Error ::" +exception.getMessage());
    }
    mLog.debug("Exited Class Name ::" + mClassName + " Method Name :: " + methodName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[@Singleton](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Singleton.html) annotation is for session beans not for utility classes

`Component-defining annotation for a singleton session bean.`

You can use [@PersistenceContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.html) annotation to specify entity manager factory and inject EntityManager.

```
 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "StudentManagementSystem")
 private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Answer (score 1):

The Singleton class `EntityManagerFactoryUtil` is still unique, but it is creating a new Instance of EntityManagerFactory on each call.

Use injection of the PersistenceContext in order to have it propagated by the container across your application.

Links: [Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqw.html)

Answer (score 0):

A [Singleton is a Design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), this means you have to implement your desired Singleton class in s uch a way that it will prevent rceating more than one Instance of it.

an Example Implementation would be for Example:

```
public class Singleton {
        private static volatile Singleton instance = null;

        private Singleton() {   }
        // Each time get Instance is called the actuall one is checked,
        // if exists no new one is created. Only if doesnt a new one is created       
        public static Singleton getInstance() { 
                if (instance == null) {
                        synchronized (Singleton.class){
                                if (instance == null) {
                                        instance = new Singleton();
                                }
                      }
                }
                return instance;
        }
}
```

In your example the Methode `getEntityManagerFactory` is equivalent to the `getInstance` Methode

Comment: Question is about [@Singleton](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Singleton.html) annotation.

Comment: Question is not explicitely about the annotation but a Singleton which doesnt work like it should.